# How to select non-url text with Vimperator?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I'm using vimperator 3.5 with firefox 17. Everything goes well except non-url text selecting. It seems that nothing about this described in the official help document. Everytime when I want to select some non-url texts I have to use my mouse to finish it. It's really annoying.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

**Jumping to the point to start your select**

You can use <kbd>/</kbd> to find whatever you want to search and use <kbd>n</kbd> to go to specific locations.

**Selecting**

Once you are there, type <kbd>c</kbd> to enter **CARET** mode where you can use <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> to move around and use <kbd>v</kbd> to select just like vim.

**Coping**

Also use <kbd>y</kbd> to yank. Happy vimp!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It should added to vimperator documentation.

Comment: As far as I know <C-c> for copying and <C-v> for pasting is also supported in the newer version of Vimperator if you're one of those who have these two in your muscle memory.
+ you can apply the advices above while in the insert mode by using <C-t> to get into TEXTAREA mode.

Comment: It's in the documentation liberator://help/various on the various page.

Comment: +1 for <C-t> in a input box. Never knew that before! :-)

Comment: Yanking into clipboard works well, unless I try it in vimperator helpall page (Linux Ubuntu 14.04, FF34). On other pages it works. C-C does not work at all for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you select wanted text with mouse, use

> Y

to copy selected text.

Good cheatsheet:http://sheet.shiar.nl/vimperator

Comment: Then just use terminal browser like w3m

Comment: See a proper answer above, an answer "use a different browser than the one that appears in the question" - is not acceptable, proposing using a mouse which contradicts the whole concept of vim - is not acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

The  answer by xxinerKYU is great but according to the reference page at liberator://help/various#various is seems that `i` is the key to caret mode.

Comment: Really? In `:helpall` and in `:usage` it tells me, `i` enters "ignore" mode. `c` described in `Uncategorized help` section talks about caret mode. I recommend you remove your answer.

Comment: on my system it says: "initial start of caret mode. Start with i, stop with <Esc>" for version 1.0. Could you please paste what it says on your installation and for which version?

Comment: When I `:helpall` and search for `caret`, it appears there twice in section "Uncategorized help" under "c" stating "Start caret mode. This mode resembles the Vim's Normal mode where you see a text cursor and can move around. If you want to select text in this mode, press v to start its Visual mode.". Using Vimperator: 3.8.3 (created: 2014/11/09 13:19:01) on FF34 on Ubuntu.